# Find which program is replacing my resolv.conf file

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, networkmanager

I use network-manager on Debian 8. My config contains some custom DNS servers, so my /etc/resolv.conf file generated by network-manager looks like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search rudloff.pro
nameserver 89.234.141.66
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 2a00:5881:8100:1000::3
```

This is perfectly fine but after a few minutes, the resolv.conf file is replaced by this:

```
nameserver 2a01:e00::1
nameserver 2a01:e00::2
```

(Those are my ISP DNS servers, which are sent by the DHCP server.)

I have no idea what is replacing this file.
Do you have any idea what could do that? Is there a way to see which process edited the file?

Answer (score 6):

Both network(mis)manager and resolvconf (only dns) can change network settings and/or dns settings (for example change the /etc/resolv.conf file as you noticed).

Though handy on a laptop which sees a lot of different (wireless) networks it is of limited practical use on servers and can even bite you, rendering the server without connectivity (say if someone accidentally or purposely adds a dhcp server on the network, suddenly network(mis)manager may decide to grab an IP address from there). If you run a server you have little use for these packages and it may be best to remove them and configure networking by hand. That way you will be sure the configuration remains consistent and unchanged.

To fix:

```
apt-get --purge remove resolvconf network-manager
```

This will not remove files such as /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces which you can edit by hand to create your own stable network configuration.

I did this as a rule when setting up a new server, or when I took over administration of a server and removal was appropriate (in 99% of cases).

Comment: I think that this is good advice in most cases, but here I like to use nmcli in order to easily manage VPN connections.
The really strange thing is the resolvconf package is not installed on this system so I really don't see what program is editing the file...

Comment: You should install auditd and set it to watch the /etc/resolv.conf file. You can add a watch on the file by simply running auditctl -w /etc/resolv.conf -k resolv-conf -p rwxa and once it's been modified by running ausearch -f /etc/resolv.conf to see what modified the file. Logs should be available under /var/log/audit/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:

1. Install and enable resolvconf
2. Edit /etc/resolvconf/interface-order and give NetworkManager a high priority

I still don't know what was messing with my resolv.conf file but at least now the one generated by network-manager is used.